# For normal people, is a guru needed or recommended to get Raja Yoga?

Tags: yoga, guru, vivekananda, raja-yoga

Consider the following excerpt from the preface of **Raja-Yoga** by Swami Vivekananda

> In the first part some simple and specific directions are given for
>   the student who want to practise, *but all such are especially and
>   earnestly reminded that, **with few exceptions**, Yoga can only be safely
>   learnt by direct contact with a teacher*. **If these conversations
>   succeed in awakening a desire for further information on the subject,
>   the teacher will not be wanting**.

Normal people in my question refers to the people who are not with any special powers or avatar etc., How to understand the above sentence? Is guru mandatory for normal people or one can attempt to do with **interest/desire** as only necessity?

Comment: I think normal people can not be 'few exceptions'.

Comment: @commommam but see the next sentence. **If these conversations succeed in awakening a desire for further information on the subject, the teacher will not be wanting.** my question is on this..

Comment: That Swamiji meant for His audience and NOT for the readers.

Comment: @commonman what about audience then? Are you saying that he will be their guru?

Comment: If you read about the expeiences of His audience, you could easily know that.So many writings of His foreign devotees are there!

Comment: If you don't have a Guru how will you know what to practice and what are the things that you should not do? Are you trying to practice Yoga upon seeing the instructions found in Swamiji's books? @hanugm

Comment: @Rickross yeah, I want to practice them from the instructions provided... At least till 5th step...

Comment: you are asking a question asking for opinions. please read forum rules...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I am asking according to scriptures only. I didn't ask for any personal opinion right?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda First sentence contains that guru is mandatory and the following sentence contains that teacher may not be needed. So i got confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need a guru? Can Lord be our Guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/why-do-we-need-a-guru-can-lord-be-our-guru)

Answer (score 2):

Well, a guru is required to each person. A selfless guru, just like Swami Vivekanand's guru Ramkrushn Paramhans. But if one cannnot find such (just like in kali yug today). Yog is preferred. But a true Yog can be taught by the Guru. Even if that Guru is not available then Shastr (Books By Rishis with Sanskrit) are the only guru left.

for your information, a shlok may have multiple meaning depending on what context you're reading it. So better option will be to learn sanskrit from scratch rather than translating it.

Comment: Welcome! Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer Does this count as a source- the following excerpt from the preface of Raja-Yoga by Swami Vivekananda
"In the first part some simple and specific directions are given for the student who want to practise, but all such are especially and earnestly reminded that, with few exceptions, Yoga can only be safely learnt by direct contact with a teacher." LOL.