# What happened to the family tree of Duhshala?

Tags: mahabharata

> Duhshala (Sanskrit: दुःशला), also spelled as Dushala or Dussala, was the only daughter of king Dhritarashtra and Queen Gandhari and sister to Kauravas in the Hindu epic Mahabharata.

What happened to the family tree of Duhshala?

Comment: She married Jayadhrata and killed in the war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duhsala’s son Suratha was ruling the kingdom. After listening to the news of Arjuna coming towards the kingdom, he fells pale and dies of fear. Suratha had a young son who challenged Arjuna. Duhsala got very scared and begs Arjuna to live her grandson alive. Arjuna feels very sad to know that Duhsala’s son died because of him and appoints Duhsala’s grandson as king of Sindh.

Reference : https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14078.htm

The Mahabharata
Book 14: Aswamedha Parva - Anugita Parva - SECTION LXXVIII - p.133

Comment: Please provide scriptural references for your answer

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: Refer [moderator’s comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34704/for-normal-people-is-a-guru-needed-or-recommended-to-get-raja-yoga/34777#comment109564_34777)

Comment: Reference added