# Where is this Srimad Bhagavatam verse about the different forms of Moksha?

Tags: philosophy, bhagavata-purana, vaishnavism, moksha, sri-vaishnava

According to Vaishnavism, there are six kinds of liberation from Samsara (the cycle of birth, death, and rebirth). They're each defined in relation to Vishnu, since Vaishnavas consider Vishnu to be the supreme goal:

1. Ekatva, or oneness with the Atma
2. Salokya, or living in the same world as Vishnu
3. Sarshti, or having the same opulences as Vishnu
4. Samipya, or being a personal associate of Vishnu
5. Sarupya, or having the same form as Vishnu
6. Sayujya, or having the same experiences as Vishnu

I discuss Ekatva in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6686/36).  But the real goal for Vaishnavas is Sayujya, where one has the privilege of eternal service to Vishnu and one has the same blissful experiences that Vishnu himself has.  In [this verse](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/29/13) of the Srimad Bhagavatam, the sage Kapila says that a devotee of Vishnu should reject the other five forms of liberation:

> A pure devotee does not accept any kind of liberation — sālokya, sārṣṭi, sāmīpya, sārūpya or ekatva — even though they are offered by the Supreme Personality of Godhead.

But apparently this isn't the only Srimad Bhagavatam verse that makes this point.  In his work the Virodha Parihara, the Sri Vashnava Acharya Vedanta Desikan [quotes another verse](http://www.oocities.org/sarojram18/RamanujandDesika/virodhaparihara1.htm):

> It is said in Bhagavatha,
>
> ḻokeśu viśnūh nivasanthi kecith
>
> samīpam rccanthi ca kecidhanye
>
> anye thu rupam sadhrsam bhajanthe
>
> sāyujyam anye sa thu mūkśaukthah
>
> '[S]ome live in the same realm with
>   the Lord which is sAlOkya; others live very close to Him, that is,
>   sAmeepya; Yet others acquire a form similar to Him known as sArupyam;
>   Some others enjoy the same pleasures with the Lord, that is sAyujya
>   which alone is called mOksha.'

My question is, where is this verse in the Srimad Bhagavatam?  At first glance I'm not able to find it. Are there any translations or commentaries on this work of Vedanta Desikan that provide a verse number for this?

Comment: Hi Keshav you said that 'sayujya is the real goal for Vaishnavas'.. Is that only for Sri Vaishnavas or Vaishnavas in general? Because this website says that even sayujya is inferior and temporary to Bhakti or Love for God. The website http://www.veda.harekrsna.cz/bhaktiyoga/philosophy.htm

Comment: @Sai Hmm, that's interesting.  The concept of these different types of liberation is certainly universal among Vaishnavas, so I assumed that their relative value was also universally agreed upon.  But it looks like Gaudiya Vaishnavas think that Sayujya is the same as Ekatva/Kaivalya, and that devotional service to Vishnu is higher than Sayujya.  Sri Vaishnavas, on the other hand, believe that Sayujya involves unending devotional service to Vishnu in his highest abode of Paramapadam, whereas Kaivalya is a different state which some Sri Vaishnavas even believe is temporary as opposed to eternal.

Comment: @Sai In any case, I wonder how Gaudiya Vaishnavas interpret the Srimad Bhagavatam verse quoted by the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Vedanta Desikan (assuming it exists).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - where(like some online resources or your personal copy) did you try finding that verse?

Comment: @Creator I tried looking in this website: http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan You looked inside http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9?

Comment: @Creator Well, I did various searches for the Sanskrit words in the verse, like this: http://www.vedabase.com/en/synonyms-index?original=lokesu Why, do you have reason to believe it's in Canto 9?

Comment: coz its related to liberation

Comment: @Creator Those Canto titles are fairly arbitrary things put by Prabhupada.

Comment: Yeah but are realted to this topic so I hope I could find anything in it, well I am currently trying to find that verse in actual book by geetapress gorakhpur. I have a doubt regarding 'enjoying pleasures ...' how can just enjoying pleasures with lord be called moksha?? It should be known as aasakti?

Comment: @Creator Well, the actual activity that you would be doing in a state of Sayujya would be eternal service to Vishnu.  But the experiences you would have would be the exact same experiences that Vishnu has.  (Like if Vishnu is saving Gajendra or giving birth to Brahma, you would feel the experience of doing those things.). By the way, you can read the Srimad Bhagavatam in Sanskrit here: http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_purana/bhagpur.itx I tried searching in this document as well, but I couldn't find the verse.

Comment: @Creator I found a book that does a good job of explaining the Srivaishnava viewpoint on this: http://tinyurl.com/mt6gtfp "According to the Vishistadvaita Vedanta, moksha is the attainment of a status equal to that of Brahman (sayujya) enjoying the blissful Brahman along with His full glory. As Vedanta Desika has rightly explained on the basis of Ramanuja's view, moksha is paripurna-brahmanubhava or full and perfect experience of Brahman and the eternal divine service (nitya-kainkarya) to which the Alvars refer is to be taken as an outflow of that ananda experienced by the jivatma in... moksha

Comment: @Creator In case you don't know, the Alwars are a group of 12 ancient Vaishnava saints whose poetry is foundational to Sri Vaishnavism.  I've posted a bunch of questions about the Alwars here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alwar

Comment: Sage Kapila said that because devotees don't want Ekatva, they want to live with Vishnu. Take the example of Hanuman, all he needs is Ram. For him, nothing else matters. The same can be said for devotees of Lord Vishnu, all they want is Vishnu. But that doesn't mean that Ekatva is lower than Sayujya, in fact it is higher.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Advaitins believe that Ekatva is the highest, but Sri Vaishnavas believe that Ekatva is lower, and some Sri Vaishnavas believe that Ekatva is only a temporary state after which the Jiva is reborn; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6686/36

Comment: Perhaps this verse was not in Prabhupada's copy of  the  Bhagavatam.

Comment: @Surya Yeah, that's a possibility.  I'm not sure if there are variant manuscripts or recensions of the Srimad Bhagavatam.

Comment: But isn't Sayujya like merging into the Lord's body?

Comment: Could it mean Bhagavatha Puran?