# Are there pictures/paintings of moksha?

Tags: moksha

I´m writing an article about pictures of afterlife/heaven in different religions. As I understood, Moksha is the biggest destination in Hinduism. But I wasn´t able to find pictures, paintings etc. of Moksha.
Are there pictures of Moksha?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE. There are no pictures of Moksha as Moksha is not a place like heaven. Moksha is when a person has attained Liberation from both earth and heaven. It is when one's soul is united with or absorbed into God. There are a few pictures of people who are in the highest state of mediation called Nirvikalpa Samadhi, which is when one's soul is absorbed completely into God while the person is still living. One example are the paintings of Buddha in meditation. Another are pictures of Ramakrishna. Google 'Ramakrishna' for some pictures.

Comment: It may interest you to know that Vaishnavas (Hindus who view Vishnu as supreme) believe in several different types of Moksha, in addition to the impersonal kind that Swami Vishwananda mentioned; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6943/36 In those other types of moksha, the soul goes to Vishnu's abode of Vaikuntha.  So a depiction of Vaikuntha would be one way to show what Moksha looks like at least according to some Hindus.

Comment: To add to the other comments, according to a branch of philosophy called Advaita, moksha is simply a state of being where One realizes His True Nature, which is Unity with all of Creation and what hindus call 'Satchidananda' or 'Truth, Consciousness and Bliss'. All the best

Comment: Moksha is state where atma meets in param-atma. So, you can also go with some kind of image like there is small light(color should be which white) could which meet a big light cloud.