# Why do Srivaishnavas consider sayujya to be highest of all liberations?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, moksha

There are different types of liberation namely:

Ekatva, or oneness with the Atma
Salokya, or living in the same world as Vishnu
Sarshti, or having the same opulences as Vishnu
Samipya, or being a personal associate of Vishnu
Sarupya, or having the same form as Vishnu

Sayujya, or having the same experiences as Vishnu

Bhagavatam talks about first 5 kinds of liberation.

Where is sayujya defined and talked about?

Why is sayujya considered topmost liberation by Shri Vaishnavas? Why are others inferior?

Comment: i think because only God is all chit and so always full of pure bliss and the objective of jeeva is to attain this state of pure bliss

Comment: Where did you get the idea that Sri Vaishnavas consider Sayujya as the topmost liberation?

Comment: Because according to Sri Vaishnavas sayujya mukti also contains all other mukti's.The liberated soul enjoys  everything experienced by Brahman himself ,except the power of creation , maintenance and dissolution.

Comment: @Ikshvaku see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6943/where-is-this-srimad-bhagavatam-verse-about-the-different-forms-of-moksha

Comment: @SwiftPushkar when do other types of liberation have separate existence without sayujya?

Comment: I think they all are separate.