# Is it possible for humans to attain the power to create Universes or Multiverses of their own through any Yoga , Mantra or Tantra Sadhana?

Tags: yoga, tantra, sadhana, human, universe

Is it possible for humans to attain the power to create Universes or Multiverses of their own through any particular sadhana? What do all the different scriptures and philosophies say about it?

It's preffered to provide a multi dimensional perspective from as many scriptures or philosophies as possible instead of a monolithic perspective from just one Scripture or School.

Comment: What do you mean by *create*? Apps, websites? How do you know that the world was created?

Comment: @User29449 I don't understand the relevance of asking 'How do you know the world was created ' when no philosophy of Hinduism believes the universe came from nothing

Comment: In tantra, there is no creation (except for Kashmir Shivaism, but not in the context you are asking!), the universe was, is, and will always remain as it should be. Eternal beings and souls are product of self, just as the whole universe and there are proper instructions by guru on how to invoke and use them, etc.

Comment: @User29449 From which Tantra did you read that?

Comment: Tantras aren't meant to be read. They are directly instructed by the gurus. If you want to get higher ideas of eternal beings, using souls, etc, then Bhairava Agamas is what you should read. But bhairava agamas have been lost, so Abhinavgupta's tantraloka.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not. This is directly against *Brahma Sutras* 4.4.17-18. It says (Swami Vireshwarananda translator):

> 17. (The released soul attains all lordly powers) except the power of creation, etc. on account of (Isvara being) the subject-matter (of all texts where creation etc. are described), and (the released souls) not being mentioned (in that connection).
>
> [part of Shankara's commentary on this verse] - ...this Sutra syas that the released souls attain lordly powers without the power of creating, preserving, and destroying the universe. Barring this they will get all other powers. Why? Because Isvara is the subject-matter of all the texts dealing with creation etc. while the liberated souls are not mentioned at all in this connection. Moreover, this would lead to many Isvaras, which may give rise to a conflict of wills with respect to creation etc. Therefore the powers of liberated souls are not absolute but limited, and are dependent upon the will of Isvara.
>
> 18. If it be said (that the released soul attains absolute powers) on account of direct teaching (of the scriptures), (we say) no, for the scriptures declare (that the released soul attains Him) who entrusts the sun etc. (with their offices) and resides in those spheres.

Comment: But what about schools other than vedanta? Do they all have the same opinion?

Comment: 'other schools'? All modern day Hindus are followers of Vyasa, whether dvaita, vishishtadvaita, or advaita. By definition 'other schools' are not Hindu...and all schools rely on the three pillars -  upanishads, bhagavad gita, and brahma sutras..

Comment: That's not completely true though. Yes most follow Vedanta but a great portion also follow many Tantric schools who don't really fall under the pale of Vedanta

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible.

**Fate of the Liberated soul**

> **Except overlordship (on the world)**, they become equal to Brahma in
> affluence, glory, form (appearance) and objects.

**Vayu Purana I.7.29**

Answer (score 0):

The Answer depends on the school one asks.

The Thenkalai school of sri vaishnavism for instance, does hold that the The Liberated Souls can attain the power to create their own universes etc. if God grants them the power to. [Copying from this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29431/34075) in the below section -

---

[Here](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48565.htm) is what Ramanujacharya says in his Sri Bhashya in sutra
4.4.14:

> In the same way as the highest Person creates out of himself, for his
> own delight, the world of the Fathers and so on; so he sometimes
> creates such worlds for the enjoyment of the released souls. But
> sometimes, again, the souls using their own creative will-power
> themselves create their own worlds, which however are included within
> the sphere of sport of the highest Person.

But there is one caveat to this, and that is explained in sutra
4.4.17:

> The released soul gets all the divine powers except that of running
> the universe (with its creation, continuance and dissolution), as is
> known from the context (which deals with God) and from the
> non-proximity (of the individual soul).

Which means that the liberated souls cannot interfere in the creation, sustenance, and destruction of the universe that is common to the
Jivas bound in samsara, but they can create, sustain, and destroy
their own worlds that are separate from the universe of the Jivas
bound in samsara.

---

[In the Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc493316.html), Sage Vishvamitra obtained the powers of creation( rivalling that of Brahmā, The creator of the universe )from Shiva as a boon after he pleased Shiva through his devotion.

> Viśvāmitra said:
>
> ‘O Lord of Devas, if you are pleased, if a boon has to be given to me,
> **O Maheśvara, let me have the great ability of creation with your favour.**
>
> **After saying “Let it be so” the holy Bull-emblemed Lord vanished** from there along with all the Gaṇas (attendants).
>
> Viśvāmitra stationed himself there with due meditation. **Rivalling
> with Brahmā, the Lord moving about on his Swan, he began the creation
> of four types.**

[With Shiva's boon, the sage created everything Brahma can create even Devas, Asuras, stars and planets, humans etc.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc493317.html) so basically his own miniature universe.

> With a keen desire, he entered water and began to meditate. Then he
> created two Sandhyās (Twilights). O Brāhmaṇas, they are to be seen
> even today.
>
> **Thereafter all the groups of the Devas were created by that
> noble-souled one. Persons travelling in aerial chariots, stars and
> planets, human beings, serpents and Rākṣasas, creepers and trees; the
> seven sages (Great Bear), Dhruva and others (Pole Star etc.) and
> sky-walkers were created.**
>
> **After creating these, the angry sage Viśvāmitra employed them in his
> own work. At that time two suns and two moons rose up in the sky
> simultaneously. There were two sets of planets. Two sets of stars
> along with the Great Bear came up, O Brahmana.**

So under certain constraints, Such a power can be attained at least as per certain schools or scriptures