# Is Jagadguru Ramanandacharya considered an incarnation?

Tags: rama, avatars, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

[Ramanandacharya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramananda) was a fourteenth century saint, one of the greatest devotees of Sri Rama, Vishishtadvaitin and the founder of the [Ramanandi Sampradaya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanandi_Sampradaya) (a sub-sect in Sri Vaishnavism). [Kabir](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabir), the famous poet-cum-saint who promoted communal harmony, is said to have been one of His disciples. Now my question is whether or not [Ramanandacharya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramananda) is considered an incarnation by His followers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ramanandis consider Ramananda to be an incarnation of Rama, whom they consider supreme. [Here](http://lordrama.co.in/sri-vaishnav-parampara.html) is what the Ramanandi Acharya Nabhadasa says in his Bhaktamala:

> The magnificence of the approach (devotion) of the Śrī-sect of Jagadguru Bhagavad Śrī Rāmānandāchārya towards Bhagavan Shri Rama appeared on this earth as a pure nectar in the form of Mantra-Raaj (Rama-mantra Parampara started by Bhagavati Sri Sita Ji). In that parampara, Hariyananda appeared after Devanandacharya, and his disciple was Sri Vaishnavacharya Raghavananda who lived in Kashi (Varanasi) and had great reverence for all devotees of Bhagavan. Then, Bhagavad Śrī Rāmānandāchārya appeared in front of Sri Raghavananda with a divine form of ascetic for the welfare of world. Devotion (of Bhagavan Shri Rama) was again strenghthened in Kaliyuga by Bhagavad Śrī Rāmānandāchārya among all four Varnas (Brahmin, Kshatriya, Vaishya, Shudra), and four Ashrama-s (Brahmcharya, Grihasta, Vanprasth, Sannyasa).
>
> **Bhagavad Śrī Rāmānandāchārya, who is Bhagavān Śrī Rāma himself** appeared in Kaliyuga, built such a great bridge which became the means for the deliverance of Jivas, to bring them across the ocean of mundane existence, just as in the past (in the Treta-yuga) Bhagavan Raghunath had constructed a bridge over the mighty ocean, and thus, innumerable Jivas were delivered and brought to supreme abode by him, (and innumerable Jivas are still being liberated by following Shri Ramanand-Padhati, Sri-sect). He proclaimed everyone has right in Prapatti, and Bhakti of Shri Rama. The twelve Mahabhagavats appeared as his twelve disciples, they are : (1) Śrī Anantānand, (2) Śrī Kabīr, (3) Śrī Sukhānand, (4) Śrī Surasurānand, (5) Śrī Padmāvatī , (6) Śrī Naraharyānand, (7) Śrī Pīpā (8) Śrī Bhāvānand (9) Śrī Raidās (10) Śrī Dhanā (11) Śrī Sēna and (12) Śrī Surasurī (Wife of Śrī Surasurānanda). His disciples, and the disciples of his disciples were illustrious and greatly renowned in the world. They championed (became the abode of) the Dashadha-Bhakti (the ten (10) forms of Bhakti, the 10th form is Prema-Bhakti, Rasika-Bhakti), and thus, they became the cause of the happiness and welfare of this world ! Bhagavad Śrī Rāmānandāchārya remained present in this world for a long time, and whoever surrendered to him, He brought everyone in the supreme abode.

I discuss this Parampara and how it traces its origins to the Sri Vaishnava sect [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17855/36).  By the way, the Ramanandi sect is not a sub-sect of the Sri Vaishnava sect, but it's part of the Sri Sampradayam of Vaishnavism, which also contains the Sri Vaishnava sect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is written in scriptures

**रामानन्दो रामरूपो राममन्त्रार्थवित्कविः।
राममन्त्रप्रदो रम्यो राममन्त्ररतः प्रभूः।।**

(अगस्त्य संहिता, १३३ अध्याय)

Srimad Ramanandacharya is Śrī Rāma himself and he is a poet who knows the meaning of Shriram's mantras. He loves Śrī Rāma Mantra only which attract Chittā of Man.

**रामानन्दः स्वयं रामः प्रादुर्भूतो महीतले।
कलौ लोके मुनिर्जातः सर्वजीवदयापरः॥
तप्तकांचनसंकाशी रामानन्दः स्वयं हरिः ॥**

The meaning is that Jagadguru Śrīmad Ramānandacharya is Śrī Rāma himself who has appeared on earth.

**मध्वो ब्रह्मा शिवो विष्णुर्निम्बार्कः सनकस्तथा ।
शेषो रामानुजो रामो रामानन्दो भविष्यतीति ॥**

~भार्गव पुराण

Also said in bhargav uppuran ie
That madhavacharya, nimbarkacharya, shesh naag will come as ramanujacharya and shri Ram himself will come as Jagadguru Ramanandacharya

**इत्युक्त्वा स्वस्य विम्बस्य तेजोराशि समं ततः ।
समुत्पाद्य कृतं काश्यां रामानन्दस्ततोऽभवत् ॥**

It is written in Bhavishya Purana III Pratisarga Khanda II Adhyay 32 that the Acharyas of all the four sampradayas appeared from Surya Vimb (here Surya does not mean Sun God but God of Even Surya according to Srimad Valmiki Ramayan.)

**अतः कलौ भविष्यन्ति चत्वारः सम्प्रदायिनः ।
श्री माध्विरुद्रसनका वैष्णवाः क्षितिपावनाः ||
रामानन्दो हविष्याशी निम्बार्कश्च महेश्वरि ।।**

Also said in padmapuran, foretelling of chatur sampradaye that jagadguru ramanandaacharya will incarnate in kaliyug.

Most importantly

****Further, according to the order of Lord Sriram himself, Acharyas emerged;**

**भविष्यंति कलौ घोरे जीवा हरिबहिर्मुखाः॥
रामाऽज्ञया हनूमान् वै मध्वाचार्यः प्रभाकरः॥
शंकरः शंकरः साक्षाद्वचासो नारायणः स्वयम्॥
शेषो रामानुजो रामो रामदत्तो भविष्यति॥
(इति सदाशिव संहिता)****

Meaning:~ In the great Kali Yuga, all living beings will turn away from God, then by the order of Shri Ramji, Hanumanji will definitely be the incarnation of Madhwacharyaji, Shankarji will be Shankaracharya in person and Vyasji himself will be Narayan. Sheshji (Lakshman ji) would be Sri Ramanujaswami and Śrī Rāma himself (Ramdatta) would be Śrī Ramānandacharya.

Also, **in bhavishya khand of agastya samhita also foretells** that bhagwan shri Ramchandra himself will incarnate as Jagadguru Ramanandacharya in kaliyug who will very learned in ved and vedangas.