# What is the story of the first Acharya of Ramanujacharya's Matham in Melkote?

Tags: history, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya, thenkalai

When the famous Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya fled Sri Rangam due to the persecution of the Shaivite Chola king (which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16200/36)), he went to Melkote in Karnataka.  It's only after the death of the Chola king that he finally returned to his beloved Sri Rangam.  But he did two things before leaving Melkote: he made a statue of himself for the people of Melkote to remember him by, and he established a Sri Vaishnava Matham there, known as [Yaduguri Yatiraja Matham](http://www.yathirajamutt.org/).  (Yadugiri is an ancient name for Melkote, and Yatiraja is a name of Ramanujacharya meaning king of Sanyasis.)  After the Thenkalai-Vadakalai split it became a Thenkalai Matham.

But my question is, what is the story of the disciple of Ramanujacharya whom Ramanujacharya appointed as the first Jeeyar or Acharya of Yadugiri Yatiraja Matham?  [Here](http://www.yathirajamutt.org/guruparamparai.html) is what the Matham's website says about him:

> Sri Deyshayee/Deshantari Kelvi Tiru-Narayana 
>  
>   Sri Ramanuja appointed Sri Deshayee to the Peetam in 1104, to propagate the Mutt abhivardhanam (growth); 
>  -With Sri Ramanuja's motivating Grace & as enshrined in the rule-book 'Niyamanappadi', this Jeer majestically continued the Nitya Bhagavat Aradhanams in & around the Cheluva Narayana-swami temple.

And here is what [this web page](http://mandayamsabha.in/mandayam-temples/) says:

> Before returning to Srirangam after 12 years, as desired by his devotees he installed an image of his own and appointed Kovil Kelvi Deshayi Tirunarayana Jeeyar as the chief executive for the management of the temple and handed over the Ramanuja seal ring to him. He also instructed the chief of the Yathiraja mutt where he lived, to be continued on the basis of the swami’s deputy to succeed. Accordingly our own community people have been heading the mutt. It is understood Deshayi Tirunarayana Jeeyar family are there among us even to-day (1980) as Deshantri’s.( Deshayi means tax collectors of Desha or country).

So Desayi Thirunarayana Jeeyar may have been from a family of tax collectors.

In any case, what do Sri Vaishnava works say about his background?  How did he become a shishya of Ramanujacharya?  Was he one of the Sri Vaishnavas whom Ramanujacharya brought along from Sri Rangam to Melkote?  Or was he converted to Sri Vaishnavism in Karnataka?

Comment: Why the downvotes?