# Which gods are Vaishnavas allowed to pray to or worship?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, worship, guru, prayer

Vaishnavas believe that Lord Vishnu is supreme hence they are discouraged from worshipping other gods like Lord Shiva, Ganesha, etc.

But what about the associates of Vishnu like Sudarshana chakra, Garuda, Vishwaksena, etc.? Can they pray to/worship them?

What about acharyas like Ramanujacharya, Vedanta Desika, etc.?

What about living acharyas, elders, etc.?

What about Hanuman?

Comment: We have Sudarshana mantra, Garuda dev mantra, etc.. and we can worship them. But look at what you need in life and what is essential. Ultimate purpose of human life is to realize Paramatma, and second whatever worship we do to Garuda, Sudarshana goes to Vishnu. Second, Sudarshana, Garuda have limits in their powers but eternal Maha Vishnu is unlimited. So why dont you worship him directly when all sacrifices, other forms of worship also reaches him?

Comment: @Akshay Post an answer instead.

Comment: *"Vaishnavas believe that Lord Vishnu is supreme hence they are discouraged from worshipping other gods like Lord Shiva, Ganesha, etc."* Can you give a reference for this ? @user15740

Comment: nitya-suris (Garuda, Vishwaksena, chakrath-azhwar), acharyas are his devotees and surrendered to Vishnu and accept him alone as supreme. same with acharyas & elders. so they can be worshipped. Hanuman is known as siriya-thiruvadi. Garuda is periya-thiruvadi i.e. smaller lotus-feet, and bigger lotus-feet when loosely translated to english i.e. they are the feet of bhagavan, carrying him.

Comment: There are many Vaishnavas who worship Shiva as the greatest devotee of Narayana.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do certain Vaishnaviters take ceremonial vows to never worship Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7392/do-certain-vaishnaviters-take-ceremonial-vows-to-never-worship-lord-shiva)

Comment: "संकर बिमुख भगति चह मोरी। सो नारकी मूढ़ मति थोरी॥" ~ [Ramcharitmanas 6.2](https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/ramcharitmanas?tid=6&tid_1=11&tid_2=8&page=0%2C1)

Comment: It would be better if comments posted on this post ask clarifications and suggest improvements rather than posting their views about Shiva Vs Vishnu Vs Shakti. Posting their own beliefs that Shiva is same as Vishnu or Vishnu is greater than Shiva or Vishnu is less than Shiva etc., are not constructive.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto A Vaishnava means belonging to Vishnu. A Vaishnava is one who surrenders himself to Vishnu and thinks he is the one who is supreme. It is the definition of Vaishnava. Questions need not post references. That is the general definition of Vaishnava. After initiation, they only worship Vishnu and not others.

Comment: Well, I don't think they discourage worshiping Ganesha, Shiva etc.

Comment: Yes, in Hindu scripture there are many verses which indicate that gods shouldn't be worshiped, and there are verses which seems say they can be worshiped. Related Q to this is https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29746/2790 we discussed that thing there.

Comment: This question is not at all opinion based. There is a defibnite definition who is a Vaishnava. Also, the OP gave some names of Gods and acharyas he wants to know to worship. This is a valid question. An initiate has definite rules whom to worship and how to worship. It would be better users refrain from posting out of context quotes and upvote them. cc @Pandya