# How do Vaishnavas interpret this verse from Padma Purana which seems to supports system of worship of five deities?

Tags: vaishnavism, worship, padma-purana

I found the following verse in Padma Purana, *Uttara-Khanda in Karttika Mahatmya* wherein Lord Krishna speaks to Satyabhama:

> saivah sauras ca ganesa  vaishnavah sakti-pujakah |
>   mam eva prapnuvantiha    varshambhah sagaram yatha ||
>   eko'ham pancadha jatah   kridayan namabhih kila |
>   deva-datto yatha kascit  putrady-ahvana-namabhih ||
>
> As the rainwater goes to the ocean, the followers of Siva, the Sun, Ganesa,
>   Visnu, so also the worshippers of Sakti come to me only. I am one, born in five ways, and play with names—as one Devadatta calls his sons etc. with (various) names. [6.88.43-44]

How do Vaishnavas interpret this verse which seems to support the system of worship of five deities?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85403/discussion-on-question-by-rara-how-do-vaishnavas-interpret-this-verse-from-padma).

Comment: There's a similar verse in Mahabharata too.

Comment: Btw the Swaminarayan Vaishnavas accept Panchatayana Puja as valid.