# Sri Vaishnava Acharyas and BharaSamarpanam

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vadakalai, sharanagati

Bharasamarpanam is a process of explicit surrender which is done by [Vadakalai sub-sect](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2835/489) of [Sri Vaishnavism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Vaishnavism). Bharasamarpanam or Bharanasyam is done after [Samashrayanam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samasrayana)

Is there any evidence of Purvaachrayas performing Bharasamarpanam(before the split between vadakalai and thenkalai sects occurred).

Note: Pancharatra Agamas approve of Bharasamarpanam so there is no doubt about its authenticity.

Comment: There is no mention of it even in Desika's life.

Comment: @M_Raghavan If it's not mentioned in Swami Deshikan's biography then why do vadakalais perform bharasamarpanam.

Comment: adiyen. desika sampradayam or vadakalai sampradayam aswell as tenacharya sampradayam only way pratised today in this kaliyuga is prapatti(barasamarpanam).in tenacharya sampradayam acharya purushas include barasamarpan together with samashrayanam that in short means barasamarpanam is a part of samashrayanam namely yaga samskaram.. while vadakalai sampradayam do this barasamarpanam saparetely as baranyasam... off course this is in general while subtle difference exist in how they are performed.to know more please undergo kalakshepam of rahasya granthams under acharyas or vidwans .

Answer (score 1):

adiyen dasan

adiyen. only way in this kaliyuga for attainment of moksha aka srivaikuntham is perform prapatti(bara samarpanam) and lead a life of true prapannan. iN desika sampradayam  prapatti or bara samarpanam  is done separately . where as in tenacharya sampradayam  prapatti(barasamarpanam) is essential part of pancha samskaram or samashrayanam.off course difference exist in how they are conducted . every srivaishnava scriptures starting from 4000 divya prabhandam to vedas and upanishad etc attest prapatti(bara samarpanam) as a means/upaya for moksha.

Comment: You should cite sources.