# Do same events repeat in every Yuga?

Tags: yuga, time

Do same events repeat in every "Yuga" ?

I mean I heard that Ramayana occurs in every "Treta Yuga" several times in vast time cycles.

In the same way for example, will Michael Jackson be born in every "Kaliyug"? Or for that matter every event that is happening now has been happening since ages and will repeat the same?

If so, then where is the point of Karma?

Is it predestined or can we influence the changes by our own deeds? If so how is it applicable? Please any one explain.

Comment: Advaitically speaking, the answer is neither yes nor no. instead the answer is it's upto You, whether or not History repeats itself. You see, history means 'past' and past is an illusion. It is only apparent. It is not real. The Mind creates an illusion that these events are happening, and the Mind itself creates an illusion that these events are repeating. All causation, repetition and differences are in the Mind. The one who realizes this, knows that History neither repeats nor is it unique. It is just 'imagined'. Thus imagine for yourself, whether or not you want it to repeat!! :)

Comment: are events predestined or can be influenced? It is combination of both. All events have been predestined, but how we take them is not predestined. Thus today my karma is to fail in exam, but its upto me whether I allow it to affect me. By choosing not to get affected, I have changed my karma :). Thus in order to change the influence of karma on my life, I need to only change my outlook on the events happening. That is the purpose of Bhakti (all events are gift from Lord Shiva), Jnana (all events are merely imaginary) and Karma Yoga (i have no desire at all why should I bother). Thank you sir!!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, cycles repeat themselves. There is scriptural evidence that says this. But there is one change. The 'jiva' that is inhabiting your body in this life is not the same jiva from your life in the previous cycle nor will it be the same jiva in the next cycle. So although your body will repeat its actions, the jiva experiencing 'your life' in the next cycle will be a new jiva whose karma is then suited for birth in your body. Your jiva will have already accumulated new karma and taken birth in another higher/lower body (or your jiva may be in a heaven or better yet attained Liberation).

Swami Vivekananda in Jnana Yoga gives the example of the ferris wheel. The ferris wheel goes round and round and when it stops it lets the passengers (jivas) out of the cars and takes on new (jivas) passengers in the same cars.

The Bhagwat Gita (2.12) says:

> "Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor these kings of men. Never will there be a time hereafter when any of us shall cease to be."

The Bhagwat Gita (9.7) says:

> "At the end of a cycle all beings, O son of Kunti, enter into My prakriti, and at the beginning of a cycle I generate them again."

The Brahma Sutra (1.3.29) says:

> "And because of the sameness of names and forms (in every fresh cycle) there is no contradiction (to the eternity of these Vedic words) even in the revolving of world cycles, as is seen from the Sruti and the Smriti."

The Vishnu Purana (I. v. 65.) says:

> "As in the rotation of the seasons, the very same signs of the different season are see repeated, so also at the beginning of a cycle the various things are created as in the previous cycle."

Rig Veda (but I don't remember the verse #) says:

> "The Lord creates in this cycle the sun and the moon as they existed in the previous cycle."

In one of the puranas, in his Boar incarnation, Vishnu turns around and says to the goddess Earth "*Every time I carry you this way..." referring to the fact that He has done the same in prior cycles*".

This is why some people have the mental ability to foretell the 'future'. It is not so much a case of being able to see the future, it is more a case of understanding the past - the prior cycle. Although they can see the past (or future) of a body, they cannot see the future of your jiva. What you do with your mind in this birth is your own making. You cannot escape the karma of the body you have (Gita 18. 60. '*you shall do even against your own will*.') but you can put your mind and heart towards God.

In a certain way, your body is eternal.

The only sure method is to realize God and escape the endless round of birth and death.....

Comment: "There is scriptural evidence that says this."  If there's scriptural evidence, then you should try to cite it.  Whatever your quote you're talking about just indicates that Vishnu's Varaha incarnation happens again and again, but that doesn't necessarily mean that all the events of the world happen again and again.  Do you know any scripture that says that?

Comment: I am revising my answer to include scripture references now.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan but we actually discussed that ramayan was only in 24th mahayuga , is this answer conflicting with ours ?

According to my knowledge events will repeat 52nd kalpa(next kalpa) but not in the 29th mahayug .(next mahayug)

Comment: @Friendy By "cycle" Swami Vishwananda means Kalpa, not Mahayuga.  In any case, we're not living in the 51st Kalpa.  A Kalpa is one day in the life of Brahma.  A Mahakalpa is a hundred years in the life of Brahma (not a hundred days).  We are living in the 51st year of the life of Brahma.  That is why in the Sankalpam (which I discuss [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3986/36)) that we utter in the beginning of any Hindu ritual, we say "Adya Brahmanaha, Dvitiya Paradhe", meaning that we're living in the second half of Brahma's life.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan thanks , i was confused with brahma age as 100days now I got it. so 1 year of brahma has how many days (kalpas) ?

Comment: @Friendy A year of Brahma has 360 days.  (For some reason Hinduism always defines years as 360 days rather than 365.  It may be due to the fact that the Hindu calendar has lunar months.)

Comment: "This is why some people have the mental ability to foretell the 'future'. " It hasn't been reported that anyone was able to foretell the future correctly