# All the kaliyug was same like current kaliyug?

Tags: kali-yuga

I want to know that there is the so  many kaliyug in kalpa, so i want  to know whether all kaliyug were same like current one with various other religions, technology ans so on.

Comment: any yug are not exactly same in kalpa,however there are chances that same yug in another kalpa can be same,

like ramayan was in 24th treta so in all other tretayugam those incidents are missing.

Comment: so there was other religious too in past  kaliyuga ?  And what about science and technology ?  why mahayuga start with sanatana dharma not other dharma

Comment: Science is always present, if you are talking about computers,mobiles these were recenty discovered so they are not in any other kaliyugam

Comment: so you want to say that  past kaliyuga people like not smart or intelligent  like our current kaliyuga ?

Comment: Resources was the same that we use in this kaliyuga so why computers were not discovered  by past kaliyuga ?

Comment: its just like saying that why android was not there in 1980, because no one discovered that.

Comment: Sanatan,hindu is just culture, I dont know why refering to it as religion ? , there may or may not be other cultures at that time but I have no knowledge about them. But egyptions pyramids texts etc are also old things so may be they too have there cultures beyond this kaliyug.

Comment: so we (human )  waited 50 kalpa for discover Power, enargy  or  light ,   like you said  different kapla has same kalyuga (may be not sure ) so past kalpa has not same kalyuga like current kaliyuga ? if there was possibllity that past kaliyuga has technology but  that kalpa or kaliyuga destroyed by the time & there is no mark of that ......

Comment: It did take only 1 kalpa not 50 kalpa,

yes it is possible that all these technologies were present in kaliyuga of past Kalpa and everything got destroyed after that, 

but ofcourse not in kaliyuga of present kalpa.

Comment: so science or human will not find out that million or trillion  years ago there was a technology like current :)... okay got it....but there is a mystery in Hinduism and I want know more about Hinduism

Comment: it is difficult for us to know what was in previous kalpa through research as everything the complete universe is regenerated after kalpa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No,

1. mahaYugs inside same kalpa are not same like ramayan was in 24th mahayug , so it is missing in other mahayugs of same kalpa.
2. But It is possible that same kaliyug was in previous kalpa 28th mahayug.

you can read further at these questions:

[Ramayana and Mahabharata in immediate yuga or after 3 cycles](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7595/ramayana-and-mahabharata-in-immediate-yuga-or-after-3-cycles)

[Time and yugas in hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/time-and-yugas-in-hinduism?rq=1)

[Does same events repeat in every Yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5438/does-same-events-repeat-in-every-yuga?rq=1)

[Why do the Vedas need to be recompiled every Dwapara Yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/why-do-the-vedas-need-to-be-recompiled-in-every-dwapara-yuga?rq=1)

Scriptural reference to matsya purana available in this question
[Did the Mahabharata and the Ramayana happen in the current Yuga cycle in the current Manvantara?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/did-the-mahabharata-and-the-ramayana-happen-in-the-current-yuga-cycle-in-the-cur?rq=1)

My answer may conflict with above questions answers, this is purely based on given matsya purana texts and my own understanding.