# Will Yashoda's soul be Krishna's mother again in the next Dwapara yuga? Do relationships with God's incarnations remain same across yugas?

Tags: krishna, gods, avatars, yuga, atma

It is clear from Geetha that a soul takes rebirth until it attains moksha state.

It is also clear from Geetha that Krishna reincarnates as himself for the establishment of dharma.

Do Krishna's relationships with other souls (when they too are reborn) repeat or vary from one yuga to other?

To put it clearly, let's say soul *S* lived as wife of Krishna in Dwapara yuga, and *S* also takes rebirth when Krishna reincarnates, will Krishna take *S* as his wife or can he take *S* as his mother, brother, sister, friend etc.?

E.g., Yashoda was the mother of Krishna in last Dwapara yuga. Suppose Krishna and Yashoda take rebirth, then is it always going to be a mother-son relation? Similarly, Subhadra was the sister of Krishna earlier and if they both take rebirth, are they again going to be sister-brother?

My doubt is:

Is there any evidence in our texts that says god can or cannot change his relations with other souls during his incarnations?

Comment: There is no mandate that a relationship should stay the same. Although, not in the context of God, there are many accounts of rebirth (of normal people) that can be found online, which show that relationships change over lifetimes. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Some other soul may take up the role of Mother yashoda.
related http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5438/does-same-events-repeat-in-every-yuga

Comment: Only his relationship with his wife/sakti remains constant across time and space. Other relationships can vary.

Answer (score 1):

Krishna is divine consciousness in His absolute purest form and he takes Avatars (not rebirths, there is a very important difference here). Traditionally and repeatedly Krishna, or Visnhu or Adi Purush ShreeHari has chosen Rishi Kashyap as his father and Aditi as his mother. Rishi Kashyap incarnated as Vasudeva and Aditi as Devaki in Krishna Avatar. Earlier Vishnu had taken birth as "Vishnu" directly as a son of Rishi Kashyap and Aditi. Aditi always remains wife or Shakti of Kashyap hence She never becomes Krishna's wife like you put it. Neither does Lakshmi ever become Krishna's mother. This is the truth.
As for Yashoda, she was a foster mother to Krishna not his birth mother. That was the soul contract.

Comment: you should cite sources