# Sada shiva is eternal

Tags: shiva

Sada Shiva is eternal . Sada shiva and lalitha devi are parents of Universe.
At the start of every kalpan Vishnu borns .From Vishnu brahma borns. From brahma's anger rudra(incarnation of shiva.) emerges from his forehead.
Brahma has life span of 100 brahma years (each brahma day is a kalpa).
Vishnu has a life of 1000 brahma life spans.

Sada Shiva is eternal.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Raju It seems you actually wanted to share what you know with others. Although, it is good to share but this site is basically in a question answer format, so if you have any doubt then you can ask a question and people can try replying to it, else this question should be closed.

Comment: @Raju- If you know the answer what is need for this? It appears you wanted to impose your ideas or express your view rather than asking a question? This has to restructured as a qiestion or it should be closed

Comment: @Aby It's actually OK (and in fact encouraged) to share your knowledge on a Stackexchange site by asking question and immediately posting an answer yourself.  I've done it myself, for example in [this question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2429/36), [this question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/791/36), and [this question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3986/36).  But yeah, posting a question that just makes statements without asking a question isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon various sects of hinduism, some belief that vishnu is eternal, some believe shiva and some that lalitha devi is eternal.

however one common term used for eternal one is saguna brahman.

by the way what is "kalpan" is it equal to 100kalpa(1 brhma life)x1000  ?

sources

Krishna in Mahabharata,

> "The ancestors
>   of civilization, and entities such as Shiva, were created by Me. They
>   do not know of this because they are illusioned by My cosmic material
>   energies."

also

> "Neither the hosts of gods nor the great sages know My origin or
>   opulences, for, in every respect, I am the source of the gods and
>   sages. He who knows Me as the unborn, as the beginningless, as the
>   Supreme Lord of all the worlds – he only, undeluded among men, is
>   freed from all sins."

but no doubt some sects may believe krishna himself was illusioned as eternal and was came from lalita-sadasiva as you say.