# Why yogam and karnam are always vishnu in sankalpam?

Tags: sankalpa, panchang

[Panchangm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchangam), the Hindu almanac is called so because it comprises of five parts (panch - five, ang - part).  The five parts are:

1. Thithi (ex: Ekadeshi, prathamai, panchami etc)
2. Vaaram (Bhaanu-Sunday, Indhu-Monday, Sthira-Saturday etc)
3. Nakshathram (Ashwini, Abhabarani, Sathabishak etc)
4. Yogam (sidha, marana, amirtha etc)
5. Karanam (kowlava, karasai, badhirai etc)

In sankaplam:

```
    hariH om tat 
    SrI govinda govinda govinda!

    asya SrI-bhagavato mahApurushasya 
    vishNor AjnayA pravartamAnasya
    adya brahmaNe dvitIya-parArdhe SrI-Sveta-varAha-kalpe
    vaivasvata-manvantare kaliyuge prathamapAde
    jambudvIpe, bhAratavarshe, bharatakhaNDe,
    SakAbde, meror dakshiNe pArSve
    asmin vartamAnAnAm vyAvahArikANAm
    prabhavAdi shashTi samvatsarANAm madhye
    vRsha nAma samvatsare
    dakshiNAyane, grIshma Rtau, SrAvaNa mAse, Sukla pakshe,
    paurNamAsyAm Subha-tithau(1), 

    Sthira-vAsara(2)-sravaNa-nakshatra(3) yuktAyAm,

    SrI-vishnu-yoga(4) SrI-vishnu-karaNa(5) Subha-yoga Subha-karaNa
    evam guNa-viSeshaNa viSishTAyAm, 
    asyAm Subha-tithau,
    ...
```

The aspects of the panchangam of the time of the performance of the sankalpam are used. However it is always said `vishnu yoga` and `vishnu karana` instead of the yogam and karnam of that moment.

Why is this so?

Comment: I think it's just done out of convenience, because people find it hard to calculate Yogas and Karanas, so they just say that it's the time of Vishnu because all times are the time of Vishnu.  I'm not sure if it's mentioned in scripture, though.  By the way, you may be interested in my question here about another aspect of the Sankalpam: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3986/36

Comment: The yogam you have mentioned is not the correct one. Sidha.. amirtha.. marana.. these things are not the correct yogam. Yogam here means relative place or alignment of sun and moon. Karanam is half of a yogam. So, two karanams make a yogam. All this sidha, marana, amirtha etc. are generic concepts and not the actual yogams.